Unable to start linux process inside dockerized app
I am trying to start linux process however I am getting error:

An error occurred trying to start process '/app/bin/x64/Debug/net8.0/SeedNKey32BitCliInterfaceLinux32' with working directory '/app'. No such file or directory

SeedNKey32BitCliInterfaceLinux32 file definitely exists since there is also SeedNKey32BitCliInterfaceWin32.exe file in same directory and starting that process is working. App is dockerized so everything happens inside docker.
This is my code:
   private static Process StartCliInterfaceProcess(string arguments)
  {
      var process = new Process();
      try
   {

         var cliInterfacePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)!;

       if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
       {
           cliInterfacePath = Path.Combine(cliInterfacePath, "SeedNKey32BitCliInterfaceWin32.exe");
       }
       else if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux())
       {
           cliInterfacePath = Path.Combine(cliInterfacePath, "SeedNKey32BitCliInterfaceLinux32");
           //cliInterfacePath = Path.Combine(cliInterfacePath, "SeedNKey32BitCliInterfaceWin32.exe");

       }
       else
       {
           throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
       }


       process.StartInfo.FileName = cliInterfacePath;
       process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
       process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

       process.Start();
       process.WaitForExit();

       if (!processs.Start())
       {
           throw new CliInterfaceErrorException("Unable to start SeedNKey CLI interface process.");
       }

       return process;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new CliInterfaceErrorException($"CLI interface error: {ex.Message}");

   }

}



Please check file existence file permissions, if docker supports 32 bits app, and try to enter the Docker container manually


You're calling process.Start() twice and check it in a non-existent process.Start() call.


